# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 to EXC_BREAKPOINT in main.m

Tags: ios, debugging

I've been searching the web (mostly this site) for answers to this question. I have found some relative questions, all of which didn't work for me or were not answered themselves.
I am writing a simple pong program, where right now I have the main load screen with a button that brings you to the game screen.
On the game screen is a button that is meant to start the ball moving by using an NSTimer.

GameComputerVSPlayer.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


int x;
int y;

@interface GameComputerVSPlayer : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIImageView *backcolor;
IBOutlet UIImageView *ball;
IBOutlet UIImageView *computerPaddleVert;
IBOutlet UIImageView *computerPaddle;
IBOutlet UIImageView *playerPaddleVert;
IBOutlet UIImageView *playerPaddle;
IBOutlet UIImageView *cornerTL;
IBOutlet UIImageView *cornerTR;
IBOutlet UIImageView *cornerBL;
IBOutlet UIImageView *cornerBR;

IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;


NSTimer *timer;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *ball;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *computerPaddleVert;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *computerPaddle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *playerPaddleVert;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *playerPaddle;


-(IBAction)nextPoint:(id)sender;
-(void)ballMovement;



@end
```

GameComputerVSPlayer.m

```
#import "GameComputerVSPlayer.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface GameComputerVSPlayer ()

@end    

@implementation GameComputerVSPlayer

@synthesize ball, playerPaddleVert, playerPaddle, computerPaddleVert, computerPaddle;


-(void)ballMovement {
ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + x, ball.center.y + y);



}

-(IBAction)nextPoint:(id)sender{
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01   target:self 
selector:@selector(ballMovement)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

x = arc4random()%9;
x = x - 5;

y = arc4random()%9;
y = y - 5;

if (y==0) {
    y = 1;
}


if (x==0) {
    x = 1;
} 
}





- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I have also tried to use NSZombie as well, but that hadn't shown me anything. Thanks in advance for your work!

Edit: I wasn't very clear with the title and issue, sorry for that. Here is another piece that of info that I left out:

Originally I had been receiving the EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 error, then i enabled NSZombie and it changed into EXC_BREAKPOINT.

I fiddled around with the code regarding the button, which led to no solution. I used the IB to disconnect the button (receive actions) from it and ran it. I was able to go and see the button, but couldn't click it (no surprise there).

Also this is my first build that doesn't involve any tutorial, so sorry if I'm making this difficult!

Not sure if any of this extra info helps or not.. but thank you all again ^.^

EDIT: EDIT:
I do have ARC enabled, that is so far the only difference that I made compared to when I followed a tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFB3QhfOwD4 ). Before that I did try without ARC enabled, but ran into similar errors with changing the view. So I'm going to try opening up the tutorial project and taking the code from that and moving it into a new project and then adjusting. I'll let you all know how it works out.

Comment: Are you initializing a new timer every time without invalidating the previous one. 
Do you have a sample project to debug?

Comment: I don't think so, I only have created one timer (that I'm aware of). and that was my first use of it.
I'm going to try to use the answer first, and I'll report back. Thanks again!

Comment: I had similar error with timer when it was trying to send message to an objects no longer existing in the memory. Check if GameComputerVSPlayer is somewhere in the memory (not only its view).

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, I've read similar comments about that. I tried using NSZombie but didn't receive any warnings. Could you please tell me a way to check?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
-(void)ballMovement: (NSTimer*) timer {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + x, ball.center.y + y);
}
```

and

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01   target:self 
selector:@selector(ballMovement:)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Notice the : after `ballMovement:`

will help you.

Comment: I just tried replacing (simply commented out) the original code with these, and it produces another EXC_BREAKPOINT error as well. Thank you for trying still >.<

I'll add some info to the original post quick, maybe I missed an important piece.

Comment: Adding parameter with `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` isn't mandatory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but this method is IBAction and probably connected to a button. Every time you touch it a new NSTimer is initialized. Keep the NSTimer in a strong property and only create one if it's not nil:

```
if (!self.timer) {
   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 
   target:self 
   selector:@selector(ballMovement)
   userInfo:nil
   repeats:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this, but I just tried to work that in and I couldn't get it to work. I'm going to edit the original post again (please look for the EDIT: EDIT:    at the bottom of the post ^.^)